# Is it possible to assign Office365 licenses via Powershell using a csv file?

Tags: powershell, automation, office365, microsoft365

What I'm looking to do here is assign specific licenses to specific accounts, that is pulled from a csv file. I have some scripts where I can bulk assign but only one license type at a time. What I'm looking to have is more granular control and bulk assign multiple license types off a csv that is something like this:

| upn | license type |
| --- | --- |
| testuser1@testdomain.com | Microsoft 365 E3 |
| testuser2@testdomain.com | Microsoft 365 E5 |
| testuser3@testdomain.com | Microsoft 365 E3 |
| testuser4@testdomain.com | Microsoft 365 F3 |

upn (userprincipalname) and license type are the column headers).Where each specified user is assigned that specific license in it's row.

So as I understand, I can do:

```
Get-MsolAccountSku
```

Which will give me all my existing license types, I can take note of the SkuId for the specific license I need, lets say for example it's testtenant:SPE_E3 , I can then do something like:

```
users = import-csv ".\bulkassignlicenses.csv"
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $upn=$user.UserPrincipalName
    $SKU= "testtenant:SPE_E3"
    Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn 
    Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $upn -AddLicenses $SKU
    Write-Host "License Assigned to UPN:"$upn 
}
```

Issue is this will only assign one type of license to the listed users in the csv file and I can't figure out how to make it iterate through a CSV and assign different types of licenses.

Comment: Certainly possible, what part of your code are you having trouble with?

Comment: So as I understand, once run Connect-MsolService and authenticate onto my tenant. I should run Get-MsolAccountSku and take note of the AccountSkuId for the specific license I need, lets say for example it's testtenant:SPE_E3 , I can then do something like: users = import-csv ".\bulkassignlicenses.csv"
    foreach ($user in $users)
    {
        $upn=$user.UserPrincipalName
        $SKU= "testtenant:SPE_E3"
        Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn 
        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $upn -AddLicenses $SKU
        Write-Host "License Assigned to UPN:"$upn 
    } 
    }

Comment: But this would only assign one specific license, my issue is I can't figure out how to make it iterate through a CSV and assign different licenses. (Sorry for the formatting of the code ^)

Comment: Redid the question now, should look better.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways you could do this, I'll show you 2 different ones. I personally think that `Group-Object` is the more elegant solution in this case.

I'm assuming that you already know all your available licenses and those licenses are already hardcoded (with no typos) on the CSV.

- Option 1: Using [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.1):

***Given the following array as example:***

```
PS /> $users

upn                           license        
---                           -------        
user.example01@testdomain.com ExampleLicense3
user.example02@testdomain.com ExampleLicense1
user.example01@testdomain.com ExampleLicense1
user.example02@testdomain.com ExampleLicense1
user.example03@testdomain.com ExampleLicense3
user.example01@testdomain.com ExampleLicense3
user.example02@testdomain.com ExampleLicense2
user.example01@testdomain.com ExampleLicense3
user.example03@testdomain.com ExampleLicense1
user.example03@testdomain.com ExampleLicense1
user.example03@testdomain.com ExampleLicense1
```

*For reference, this is how the array looks after grouping it:*

```
Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                                     
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                                     
    4 user.example01@testdom... {@{upn=user.example01@testdomain.com; license=ExampleLicense3}, @{upn=...
    3 user.example02@testdom... {@{upn=user.example02@testdomain.com; license=ExampleLicense1}, @{upn=...
    4 user.example03@testdom... {@{upn=user.example03@testdomain.com; license=ExampleLicense3}, @{upn=...
```

**Code:**

```
$users | Group-Object upn | ForEach-Object {
    # Note: $_.Group.License may or may not be an array.
    # Since -AddLicenses can take string[] as input this shouldn't be a problem
    Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.Name -AddLicenses $_.Group.License
}
```

- Option 2: Using [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.1):

***Given the following array as example:***

```
PS /> $users

upn                           license                                                        
---                           -------                                                        
user.example02@testdomain.com ExampleLicense2;ExampleLicense1;ExampleLicense1                
user.example01@testdomain.com ExampleLicense3;ExampleLicense1;ExampleLicense2;ExampleLicense1
user.example03@testdomain.com ExampleLicense3;ExampleLicense2;ExampleLicense3;ExampleLicense2
```

*Note: I'm using a semicolon `;` as delimiter however you should decide which is the proper delimiter for this example.*

**Code:**

```
$users | ForEach-Object {
    $licenses = $_.license -split ';'
    Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.upn -AddLicenses $licenses
}
```